# How to send the location coordinates from Emulator Control to HTC Wildfire real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, geolocation

I have a location based app which displays the location using the geo-coordinates received from Emulator Control of DDMS perspective. I have installed my app in HTC Wildfire phone but I am unable to send location coordinates from Emulator Control as it is "Greyed out"(i.e,User input to latitude and lomgitude of Emulator Control is not possible).I have placed permission of "INTERNET","ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION","ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION","ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" permissions correctly in Android manifest.xml. But still this problem is appearing .Please help me how to send geocoordinates to my HTC mobile from Emulator Control.

Comment: Why do you want to send geo coordinates from an emulator to a phone?

Answer (score 0):

To use DDMS on your application running on the phone you have to set the debuggable attribute of the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml and you have to start your app.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:debuggable="true">
```